# Die Bedeutung von Arschwasser

Tags: phrase, meaning-in-context, colloquial

Was bedeutet das Wort ***Arschwasser*** in diesem Kontext? Ich habe versucht, in meinem Wörterbuch nachzuschlagen, aber ich habe es nicht finden können.

> Benehme mich auf deiner Birthdayparty wie ein Schwein, yeah.
>   Dein Album war krass; mein Album war krasser.
>   Wenn meine Jungs kommen, läuft bei euch **das Arschwasser**.
>   Guck, wie ich dir jetzt ne Schelle auf die Backe gebe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Es gibt die derbe Redewendung

> jemanden schleifen, bis ihm das Wasser im Arsch kocht

Sie bedeutet, „jemanden äußerst hart exerzieren lassen“ (Soldatensprache) oder „jemanden äußerst hart trainieren lassen“ (im Sport).

Comment: Wobei _Arschwasser_ speziell eben den Schweiß meint, der sich zwischen den Pobacken sammelt.

Comment: Nie so gehört, aber es ist logisch gesehen der Schweiß der den Rücken hinunter läuft. Also `Wenn meine Jungs kommen, bekommt ihr viel Angst`

Answer (score 3):

Damit ist der Angstschweiß gemeint, der sich zwischen den Pobacken in der Analfalte sammelt.

Der Song behandelt eine Rivalität zwischen zwei Sängern, die in Form von Musikstücken ausgetragen wird. Dabei wird in den Songtexten der jeweils anderen Partei Gewalt angedroht, oder es werden als schlecht empfundene Eigenschaften des Kontrahenten publik gemacht.

**Analyse des zitierten Songtext-Ausschnittes:**

> Benehme mich auf deiner Birthday-Party wie ein Schwein, yeah

Der Sänger berichtet davon, auf der Geburtstagsfeier seines Kontrahenten gewesen zu sein, und erzählt (offenbar voll Stolz), sich dort schlecht benommen zu haben.

> Dein Album war krass;

Mit dieser Eröffnung wird dem Gegner zum letzten Musik-Album gratuliert, ...

> mein Album war krasser.

... dieses Lob wird aber sofort relativiert, indem die eigene Leistung als noch besser beschrieben wird. Durch das vorangegangene Lob der gegnerischen Leistung wird die eigene Leistung noch weiter erhöht.

> Wenn meine Jungs kommen, läuft bei euch das Arschwasser.

Das bedeutet: Wenn meine Anhänger (zu dir und deiner Anhängerschaft) kommen, werdet ihr so viel Angst vor meinen Leuten haben, dass euch der Angstschweiß über den Rücken läuft und sich in der Analfalte sammeln wird.

> Guck, wie ich dir jetzt ne Schelle auf die Backe gebe.

Das bedeutet: Gib acht und höre, wie ich dir jetzt (im übertragenen Sinn) eine Ohrfeige gebe (indem ich in weiteren Verlauf dieses Liedes über dich lästere).

Answer (score 1):

Noch einmal Lyrics, diesmal von Peter Fox in seinem Song "Fieber": "Riesige Menschenmassen pilgern Richtung Alaska, die einzige Flüssigkeit in der Stadt ist mein Arschwasser!" Aus dem Kontext ergibt sich: Extreme Hitze, Schwitzen und die daraus resultierende Ansammlung von Flüssigkeit in bestimmten Regionen des Körpers. Das ist es.